# Processing user input in simple Python program

Tags: python

I am making a program that gives the user a random integer from 1 to 10 as a diameter using a list and they have to calculate the circumference using Pi as 3. So far everything is working fine apart from a thing about bad inputs. When the user answers the question, no matter the answer, it says it is incorrect.

Any chance to get some help? Here is my code:

```
import turtle
import random
turtle.speed("fastest")


pi = 3
minNumber = 4
maxNumber = 10
score = 0
listNmbers = []

a = [1,3,5,7,9]

red = random.random()
green = random.random()
blue = random.random()

num1 = random.choice(a)


def drawSquare():
    for i in range(4):
        turtle.begin_fill()
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.right(360/correct)


turtle.penup()
turtle.setpos(-700,-200)
turtle.fillcolor("green")


def askCir(cirAnswer):
    try: 
        user = input("What is the circumference of a circle if the diameter is " + str(num1) + " and Pi is 3?")
        cirAnswer = int(user)   
    except:
        print("Please input a number only!")
        cirAnswer = 0;
        cirAanswer = askCir(cirAnswer)



print("Welcome! What is your name??")
name = str(input())
print("Hello", name,"you need to calculate the circumference of a circle when given a diameter. To calculate the circumference, use the equasion; Pi x Diameter (Pi = 3")

def getNumbers():
    num = input("how many questions would you like to answer? (Pick between 5 and 10)")
    try:
        numbers = int(num)
    except:
        print("That is not a number!")
        return getNumbers()
    goodInput = minNumber < numbers < maxNumber

    if not goodInput:
        print ("That is not between 5 and 10. Please input an integer between 5 and 10.")
        return getNumbers()
    else:
        return numbers
numbers = getNumbers()    


for i in range(numbers):
    red = random.random()
    green = random.random()
    blue = random.random()
    turtle.color(red,green,blue)
    num1 = random.choice(a)
    correct = num1 * 3

    cirAnswer = 0;
    cirAnswer = askCir(cirAnswer)
    print(str(correct))

    if cirAnswer == correct:
        print("That's Correct! Well Done")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("Sorry that is incorrect")

    for k in range(correct):
        turtle.color(red,green,blue)
        drawSquare()

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(150)
```

Comment: I was having problem all the time with input, so try raw_input i think it will help. I did't go to deep in your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return cirAnswer` statement is missing from `askCir`. Also there should be a loop in `askCir` in case the user inters invalid answers multiple times.

Comment: It helps will the incorrect but now if they enter a string, it tells them to enter an integer only. If they then enter the correct answer it says its incorrect. Any idea why?

Comment: @Brandon: To debug this, add `print (cirAnswer, correct)`, run it, and see if those variables have the same type, same value etc. If you can't figure out, ask it in a separate question.